# How to create a Global Initialization in NUnit 3.2?

Tags: c#, testing, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I've trying to design a test suit to run a global initialization before all my tests. We can consider that exists tests in differents classes and namespaces. In NUnit documentation I only found a attribute named OneTimeSetUp, but it works only for tests in the same namespace.

So, I designed using inherting. all my tests classes inhert a base test class where his constructor does the global inicialization (whith the help of a static variable to check if it was or not initialized), and the same to a global tear down in the destructor.

Using it I could create my scenario. But when the test suit runs, the base test class creates new objects because there are tests in differents classes and namespaces. It cause a overloard in the system and the next tests runs slow: the first test runs in 50 seconds, while another (that do the same thing but in a different namespace) runs in 120 seconds.

There is a better way to create a global inicialization and a global teardown without impact the test performance

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are correct that `OneTimeSetUp` only works for tests in the same namespace, but as the 
[`SetUpFixture` documentation](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute) notes:

> A SetUpFixture **outside of any namespace** provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly.

So the class would look like this:

```
using System;
using NUnit.Framework;

[SetUpFixture]
public class TestInitializerInNoNamespace 
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void Setup() { /* ... */ }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void Teardown() { /* ... */ }
}
```

Comment: So in this case, I should use `SetUpFixture` instead of `TestFixture`, as you write in your code example, correct?

Comment: I will try both cases and, if some of these works, I will consider your awnser. Thanks!

Comment: Oops, sorry, it should have been SetUpFixture. Edited.

Comment: I received an error message when i tried to change the class structure to the awnser example: `Message: OneTimeSetUp: SetUpAttribute not allowed in a SetUpFixture`

Comment: Ok,I fixed the error. Was necessary the methods [SetUp] and [TearDown] to other class (I use they to write in a log the tests success/failure). Also, I remove all inherts of the [SetUpFixture] class from my tests class and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: Anybody having performance problems with this approach? I've noticed that it adds ~4 seconds to my test runs.

Comment: I used to use one of these, but then I got rid of it as I didn't need it any more. If you can get a MVCE together to demonstrate the delay you could [raise an issue](https://github.com/nunit/nunit/issues)